# Why would all of the references break on my Blazor project when I add my other project as a reference?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, blazor

I can't figure out why it's happening, but whenever I add my other project as a reference to my Blazor project, all of the Blazor project's references break; and removing the project as a reference fixes all the other references. Other projects (e.g. adding a new Console app) reference it fine, it just seems to be an issue with the Blazor project.

Here is the .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
    <RazorLangVersion>3.0</RazorLangVersion>
    <ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>service-worker-assets.js</ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="3.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Build" Version="3.2.1" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="3.2.1" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="3.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\.FtxApi\FtxApi\FtxApi.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CryptoTradingBot\CryptoTradingBot.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ServiceWorker Include="wwwroot\service-worker.js" PublishedContent="wwwroot\service-worker.published.js" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I've never worked with Blazor before; Is there a compatibility issue or something else that might cause this?

Comment: First time: What flavor of Blazor do you use, client or server ?

Comment: Hmm I'm assuming client. I created it with the .NET Core 3.1 "Blazor WebAssembly App" template with PWA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, the project I was trying to reference was a console project which Blazor projects don't "like" (IIRC referencing this project within other projects worked without issues). I suspected this might be the cause at first, and thought changing the project output to library was good enough but that was a misunderstanding. I moved everything into a new SharedProject since I'm planning to replace the console with a Blazor GUI, and referenced that instead. Everything is working properly now.